# Apache Alias issues

Tags: apache, webserver, httpd.conf

I'm new with configuring apache, I'm creating a virtual host and having a problem. Here is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName seeddms.com
ServerAlias www.seeddms.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /sd “/var/www/seeddms/seeddms43x/www/index.php"
<Directory "/var/www/seeddms/seeddms43x/www/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /whichserver "/var/www/html/index.html"
```

When I comment out this:

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It says forbidden access and if it is present in the config file then it says url `/sd` not found. Please help me with this issue and also suggest me a source where I can understand the apache config better.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong character `"` in your alias near the /sd.

Instead of this :

```
Alias /sd “/var/www/seeddms/seeddms43x/www/index.php"
```

Try to write this :

```
Alias /sd "/var/www/seeddms/seeddms43x/www/index.php"
```